# git tab-completion does not work on Debian Wheezy but works on Squeeze

Tags: bash, debian, apt

My question is about git command tab-completion, i.e. when I type `git stat`
and hit Tab, it completes the command line to `git status`.  (Where
applicable, this also works with remote names and branch names.)

What confuses me is that without additional configuration on any of the boxes,
on the machine with older git and stable Debian it works, while on the laptop
it does not.  Shouldn't that be the *other way around*?  Shouldn't the fancy
things tend to rather be in testing than stable?

On my VPS, where:

```
aloism@srv:~$ git --version
git version 1.7.2.5
aloism@srv:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID:     Debian
Description:        Debian GNU/Linux 6.0.5 (squeeze)
Release:            6.0.5
Codename:           squeeze
```

and on my laptop:

```
lennycz@laptop:~$ git --version
git version 1.7.10.4
lennycz@laptop:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID:     Debian
Description:        Debian GNU/Linux testing (wheezy)
Release:            testing
Codename:           wheezy
lennycz@laptop:~$
```

There's nothing interesting in ~/.gitconfig on any of the boxes.

Can anybody explain it?  A bug in git?  Any more research ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that package bash-completion, which enables completion for other
packages that add their script to /etc/bash_completion, is not instaled on the
laptop.

> Shouldn't that be *the other way around*? Shouldn't the fancy things tend to rather be in testing than stable?

Well, it sounds logical, but Debian kind of breaks this minimalistic principle
since Lenny as it installs also recommended pakages by default.  You can [disable this behavior](http://linux.koolsolutions.com/2009/01/07/howto-tell-apt-get-not-to-install-recommends-packages-in-debian-linux/), though.

Apparently Debian installer does not use this setting for Wheezy, reason being
another question.